# How to change a source file content on every eclipse build?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot

My server deployment is zero downtime. So whenever I deploy my changes and call the Health Check API, I don't know if the result is of my latest deployment or the of the previous one. Can I somehow change the content of my **PingController.java** and return the last build time on every Eclipse build ?

Comment: what about to have a version.id in the application.properties file and read this value out?

Comment: But then I'll have to manually update the version.id property in application.properties right ? I want this to automatically happen using some script in Eclipse. For example my controller file content should change to:
`@RequestMapping(value="/ping") public String ping() {      
        return "<build_time>";
    }`